# What is the need for shuffling in tf.data.Dataset when fitting data into TFBertForSequenceClassification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to understand [this example](https://gist.github.com/papapabi/124c6ac406e6bbd1f28df732e953ac6d) on using Bert for sequence classification with a custom example. My question is fairly simple: what is the need for:

```
train_data = train_data.shuffle(buffer_size=num_examples, reshuffle_each_iteration=True) \
        .batch(BATCH_SIZE) \
        .repeat(-1)
```

If I don't shuffle the data, I get an error:

```
ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
for '{{node strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0,
 ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1, strided_slice/stack_2)' 
with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: 
input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```

So, to me, it seems that shuffling is not only shuffling but doing something else and I don't exactly understand what.

Comment: Can you show how exactly does your code look like when you don't shuffle?

Comment: @Jindřich I think I found the issue. The problem was not on the shuffling but rather on `.batch` I must ensure that the train data comes in batches